# All sieves form a set

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, set-theory

I am currently trying to understand SGA 4, and the set-theoretical  terms disturb me (such as universes). Let $\mathscr{U}$ be  a universe and $C$ a $\mathscr{U}$-category (in the terms of SGA 4). In Proposition 4.2 of SGA 4, page 13, it said      `` the arrows above defines a bijection of the sets of sieves of $X$ and the set of all subobjects of $X$ in $\widehat{C}$'' ($\widehat{C}$ is the category of presheaves in $\mathscr{U}$-sets on $C$). But why the collection of sieves of $X$ (or of the subobjects of $X$ in $\widehat{C}$) is a set?

Comment: A subobject of $X$ is uniquely determined by a subset (not arbitrary) of the disjoint union of the sets $X(c)$, where $c$ runs over all objects of $C$. I think that asking this at math.stackexchange would be more appropriate.

Comment: But how to guarantee that the index collection $C$ is a set? By definition only $Hom(x,y)$ is $\mathscr{U}$-small.

Comment: That $C$ is an $\mathscr U$-category, does not it mean that also the set of objects of $C$ is $\mathscr U$-small?

Comment: The collection of objects of every category is a set. That's the advantage to using universes.

Comment: @ReidBarton So $C$ is an $\mathscr U$-small category, right? Then it is straightforward that the collection of subobjects of any object of $\hat C$ is $\mathscr U$-small.

Comment: I now checked SGA 4 and indeed $\mathscr U$-categories do not necessarily have $\mathscr U$-small sets of objects. So it is more subtle. I believe one has to use the axiom that every set belongs to some universe to ensure that, although neither sieves nor subobjects form an $\mathscr U$-small set, the bijection between them is still well-defined.

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე
A $\mathcal U$-category is $\mathcal V$-small where $\mathcal V$ is a universe containing $\mathcal U$ as an element.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Right. But the set of subobjects of a presheaf on an $\mathscr U$-category with values in $\mathscr U$-sets need not be $\mathscr U$-small, right? For example, subobjects of the terminal presheaf on the discrete category with a non-$\mathscr U$-small set $S$ of objects are bijective with all subsets of $S$.

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე Right. Fortunately, as far as I can see, there has been no claim that these sets of subobjects or of sieves are $\mathcal U$-small. The quotation in the question merely calls them sets, which they are.  Indeed, once $\mathcal U$ is available as a set, ZF is enough to ensure that these sets exist, without needing a bigger universe $\mathcal V$.